# jquery masonry 60% and 40% columns

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to put together a responsive jquery masonry layout - but allow for the first box to be 60% width (with 100% height), and the other two boxes to be 40% width (with 50% height).

I can get it working if the columns are set to 50%, but I cannot seem to get it to work with the first box being 60%, and the other two being 40% width. Masonry puts the second two boxes underneath my first box instead.

Here's the code that I'm using (which works with 3 boxes, all at 50% width). I've hashed out the CSS which I was trying to use to make it 60% / 40%.

html:

```
<div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-width60 grid-item-height100">aa</div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-width40 grid-item-height50">bb</div>
        <div class="grid-item grid-item-width40 grid-item-height50">cc</div>
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
        columnWidth:'.grid-sizer',
        itemSelector:'.grid-item',
        percentPosition:true
    });
```

css:

```
section.slideshow .grid{width:100%;height:100%;background:#000}
section.slideshow .grid-sizer,section.slideshow .grid-item{width:50%}

/*section.slideshow .grid-item-width60{width:60%}
section.slideshow .grid-item-width40{width:40%}*/

section.slideshow .grid-item-height100{height:100%;background:#f0f}
section.slideshow .grid-item-height50{height:50%;background:#f99}
```

Any help would be appreciated! I've tried following what is said to do with responsive layouts here: https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok for anyone else having this issue, it was sorted by this:

```
section.slideshow .grid-sizer,section.slideshow .grid-item{width:20%}
```